# Difference between Microsoft.AspNetCore.* and Microsoft.Extensions.* Nuget packages?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

There seems to be a lot of overlap between `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` and `Microsoft.Extensions.*` Nuget packages.

A few examples:

- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` vs `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`
- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` vs `Microsoft.Extensions.Http`

And there seems to be a lot of similar dependencies in them. But what should be the deciding factor(s) in choosing one or the other?

Comment: this may help; https://stackoverflow.com/a/50850913/18391068

Comment: generally, Microsoft.AspNetCore are packages specific for ASP.NET Core, and Microsoft.Extensions are more general-purpose libraries that provide features and utilities that can be used in a wide range of applications. I would say that 99% of the time, if you are developing an ASP.NET Core project, and you encounter a duplicate package across these two, you'll be fine sticking with the AspNetCore namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
[image]

Asp.net Core is web app framework, and its package is for web app development.
Extensions can be used in other applications such as WPF.
They have some common libraries. But many AspNetCore package latest version is years ago. Extensions could be a better choice if you can use them.

Comment: It's probably just as simple as that. Tnx!